# Filtering Splunk results based on a numerical value in the log entry

Tags: regex, splunk

We have an application that generates logs in the following manner:

```
task1: spend 51milliseconds
task2: spend 40milliseconds
task3: spend 30milliseconds
task1: spend 101milliseconds
```

We want to filter Splunk results such that it only shows logs entries where spend is more than 100milliseconds.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried to achieve what you need? What worked? What didn't?

Comment: Right now I export the results to Google Spreadsheet and then parse it using Google Apps Script :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
 | rex "spend (?<timespent>.*)milliseconds" |WHERE timespent>100
```

Comment: Maybe `"spend (?<timespent>[0-9]+)milliseconds"` will be a bit more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Try,(assuming field name is log)

- selects 3 digit values, by excluding first digit-if it is 0

  `| regex log="spend [1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}milliseconds"| table log`

OR try

- this will include morethan 3 digit values also

  `| regex log="spend [1-9]{1}\d\d+milliseconds"| table log`